# Scrollbar shows only x-scroll

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I'm having an odd problem... My textarea shows only x-sroll... Dunno why y-scroll is not showing.. Have tried set all to !important, position: relative with z-index: 999999 etc.

x-scroll is only for testing.

Anyone recognize this problem?
I'm also using foundation 3.

css:

```
div.forum_new_thread textarea{
position: relative;
width:488px;
top: 131px;
height:212px;
border: none;
resize:none;
background: #f4f9f4;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-ms-border-radius: 0px;
-o-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:scroll;
font-size: 18px;
padding:15px;
color:#2f2f2f!important;
font-family: 'vaud_display_medium';

}



div.forum_new_thread textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 18px;
border-left:1px solid #5a5a5a;
}

div.forum_new_thread textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track {

background:black;

}

div.forum_new_thread textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background:#5a5a5a;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

[image: Scrollbar]

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you like. First time you can't see x-scroll but while enter text into textarea you can see it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        div.forum_new_thread textarea{
position: relative;
width:488px;
top: 131px;
height:212px;
border: none;
resize:none;
background: #f4f9f4;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-ms-border-radius: 0px;
-o-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:scroll;
font-size: 18px;
padding:15px;
color:#2f2f2f!important;
font-family: 'vaud_display_medium';

}



div.forum_new_thread textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 18px;
border-left:1px solid #5a5a5a;
}

div.forum_new_thread textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track {

background:black;

}

div.forum_new_thread textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background:#5a5a5a;
border:1px solid black;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div >
            <div class='forum_new_thread'>
                    <textarea>

                     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                       took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries
                       but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                        release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
                         PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

                    </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to hide x-scroll?

Comment: Got it working! Thnaks for the help... For some reason when I restarted my apache server it started to work...

Comment: Don't forgot to like.